# Instantiating Template Object within a template

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I'm taking a C++ class, and am having trouble figuring out one of the homework assignments. We are given the following class (which I've added to my .h file, and we were told not to modify), and told to implement the iterator class.

```
template <typename T>
class IntegerRange
{
public:
  class iterator;

  IntegerRange(T low, T high) : low_(low), high_(high)
  {
    assert(low <= high);
  }

  const iterator begin() const {return iterator(low_); }
  const iterator end() const {return iterator(high_); }

private:
      const T low_, high_;
};
```

We were given the following of a way it would be used:

```
IntegerRange<int> r1(-2, 3);
copy(r1.begin(), r1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));  //-2 -1 0 1 2

IntegerRange<unsigned> r2(0, 6);
copy(r2.begin(), r2.end(), ostream_iterator<unsigned>(cout, " ")); //0 1 2 3 4 5
```

For starters, I was just trying to get the code to compile so I could play around with it and figure it out, but I'm having a hard time with even that. I added the following code to the same .h file, but am getting the error "Implicit instantiation of undefined member 'IntegerRange::iterator'"

```
template <typename T>
class iterator
{
public:
  iterator(T data) : data_(data) {}

private:
  T data_;
};
```

I'm not looking to have anyone tell me how to do the whole assignment - just wondering how I can even get it to compile? Thanks! Full main.cpp & IntegerRange.h files below:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "IntegerRange.h"
#include <algorithm>
 using std::copy;
 using std::cout;
 using std::ostream_iterator;

 int main()
{
  IntegerRange<int> r1(-2, 3);
  copy(r1.begin(), r1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));  //-2 -1 0 1 2

  IntegerRange<unsigned> r2(0, 6);
  copy(r2.begin(), r2.end(), ostream_iterator<unsigned>(cout, " ")); //0 1 2 3 4 5
  return 0;
}

//IntegerRange
#ifndef Homework7_IntegerRange_h
#define Homework7_IntegerRange_h

#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class iterator
{
public:
  iterator(T data) : data_(data) {}

private:
  T data_;
};


template <typename T>
class IntegerRange
{
public:
  class iterator;

  IntegerRange(T low, T high) : low_(low), high_(high)
  {
    assert(low <= high);
  }

  const iterator begin() const {return iterator(low_); }
  const iterator end() const {return iterator(high_); }

private:
  const T low_, high_;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: (you still need to implement `++` operators etc.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class IntegerRange
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        iterator(T data) : data_(data) {}
        const T& operator*(){return data_;};
    private:
        T data_;
    };

    IntegerRange(T low, T high) : low_(low), high_(high)
    {
        assert(low <= high);
    }

    const iterator begin() const {return iterator(low_); }
    const iterator end() const {return iterator(high_); }

private:
    const T low_, high_;
};


int main()
{
    IntegerRange<int> r1(-2, 3);
    auto it=r1.begin();
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`IntegerRange` defines an inner class `iterator`.

```
template <typename T>
class IntegerRange
{
public:
  class iterator; // forward declaration
  ...
```

I think, the problem is that you are not implementing an inner class of `IntegerRange` but a standalone class:

```
template <typename T>
class iterator
{
public:
  iterator(T data) : data_(data) {}
  ...
```

So the compiler thinks it is a complete unrelated class. Try to move your implementation of `iterator` inside the `IntegerRange` class (for example, replacing the forward declaration by your implementation).

As you said, you must not update the `IntegerRange` class, you have to qualify the `iterator` class using this idea:

```
class MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass
{
  // ...
};
```

Comment: That seems to have helped - although now I'm getting an error that says "Invalid operands to binary expression ('IntegerRange<int>::iterator' and 'IntegerRange<int>::iterator') in reference to the copy function

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to forward declare `class iterator` declare it outside of `class IntegerRange`. Or did you want to declare it as a `friend` class? e.g.,

```
template <typename T>
class IntegerRange
{
public:
  friend class iterator;

  // ...
};
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, the assignment specified that we should not modify the definition of the IntegerRange class